# How to extract values in an array that returns to arrays - HttpClient Service - Angular 7+

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable, angular-httpclient

I am having a hard time getting the grasp of managing data once it's returned from a Http Request in Angular 7+

The Service for getting each location looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Base } from '../interfaces/base';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {

  base$: Observable<Base[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllBases() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    return this.http.get(
      'https://megaphone-test.herokuapp.com/api/base/getAllBases',
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().append('x-access-token', token)
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I am consuming this in a component like this (right now its a massive fail) For brevity I am not sending the entire document but the meat and potatoes is right here:

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() node: string;
  base$: Base[];
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(public baseService: BaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.baseService.getAllBases()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.base$ = res['bases'];
      }
    );
  }

}
```

If I console log that response and look in the console I get two arrays tucked inside one parent array. So of course, res['bases'] looks some thing like:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, basePhoneNumber: "+18442367381", baseName: "Test AFB 1", bandwidthUserId: "u", bandwidthApiToken: "t", …}1: {id: 2, basePhoneNumber: "+12345678908", baseName: "Test AFB 2", bandwidthUserId: "u", bandwidthApiToken: "t", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

So What I am struggling to comprehend is how can I take those and put the data into something that would make this work?

```
<ng-container [clrLoading]="loading">
    <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let base of base$">
        <!-- {{ base?.baseName }} -->
        {{ base.baseName }}
    </clr-tree-node>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Does the  `*ngFor` loop not work? You seem to be doing the correct thing.
 One thing to note, you should rename `base$`  to `base` as `$` is a convention used for an observable and since you are already in `subscibe()` it is just a plain object now.

Comment: No the *ngFor is not working. I just changed base$ to bases. Still no dice. I think it has something to do with the fact the JSON response from the API put each location inside its own array.

Comment: The `$` was not supposed to change the behaviour, was just a convention.

Comment: Also, i think the main issue you are having, is `ChangeDetection`. 
If `base[]` is `[ {id: 1, basePhoneNumber: "+18442367381", baseName:..}, {...}]` you shuld be able to iterate using `*ngFor`. maybe i a missing  something?

Comment: Also, do you have any console error?

Comment: No the console I have is simply spitting out the bases with no issue...

Comment: So, could you try by modifying your constructor to add `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef`. and inside the `subscribe` after `this.base$ = res['bases'];`
add ->   `this.cdr.detectChanges();`
I suspect your change detection is not working. This will force your UI to to be re-rendered

Comment: See below... I forgot to set the loading status to false thereby not allowing the *NgFor to do it's job...

Answer (score 0):

Oh my,

I am simply just missing the mark today! I found out what was causing the issue!

[You see, I am using the Clarity UI framework.](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/tree-view)

So the example for using the Tree view shows:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "lazy-loaded-locations",
    template: `
        <ng-container [clrLoading]="loading">
            <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let location of locations">
                {{location}}
            </clr-tree-node>
        </ng-container>
    `
})
export class LazyLoadedLocationsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() node: string;
    locations: string[];
    loading: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
        // This would be a call to your service that communicates with the server
        this.locations = fetchLocations();
    }
}
```

So what I was doing wrong was not setting the loading state to false after making my API call. Once I set it to false the names of the bases came right up! Thanks for taking the time to jump in and examine with me. Feel like a real putz right now.

Cheers,

Coach Allen